# anaconda launcher links don't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, osx-mavericks, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I've installed anaconda on mavericks osx. When I'm trying to install ipython notebook from launcher app - it shows message that app is installing, but nothing happens after. Also links in launcher don't work and I can easily start ipython notebook from terminal. So I guess something wrong with launcher itself.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I have a similar problem on MacOSX 10.7.5

Comment: So far I found that links on OSX not working because of switch from PySide to PyQt.

Comment: However it's least of my concern. Launcher behavior still is pretty weird. I've reinstalled anaconda, after went straight to launcher and it was working good, I was able to install all three components. But after reboot launcher no more launching. I can start everything I need from terminal, except launcher and it gives me logs.

Comment: @BobbyDigital Same problem here. The system is OSX 10.10.2. Have you found the solution?

Comment: Yes, Brian's solution down here worked perfectly. Did you try it? However your system setup is fresher than mine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
conda install -f launcher
conda install -f node-webkit
```

The Launcher application requires both of these on OSX.

It is also a good idea to make sure you Anaconda environment is up to date first with:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

Comment: After running all the commands in the above answer, my launcher is now working. Basically my ananconda was updated from 2.0.1 -> 2.1 and the launcher in that is working perfectly.

Comment: `launcher` is now deprecated in favor of `anaconda-navigator`. See @sushmit answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37844383/2005869

Answer (score 6):

As of conda 4.1.0 it is recommended to use navigator , For me the launcher stopped working . To install conda navigator

```
conda install anaconda-navigator
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  Anaconda full suite , that include installing all the tools and necessary packages ,it works fine for me , I didn't use the Launcher !

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on MacOSX Yosemite. Was able to run the launcher by typing 'launcher' in the terminal. And then by changing the bash profile IPython Notebook started working

https://coderwall.com/p/-k_93g/mac-os-x-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8-in-python